# How to run docker containers in their network with an external gateway?

Tags: linux, networking, docker, docker-compose

I have some images that I'm managing with docker-compose and I need to run them in a different network than that of the host machine (which is running Ubuntu 16).

Host machine has IP 10.0.1.19/24 and gateway 10.0.1.1.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    ...
    networks:
      ab-net:
        ipv4_address: 10.1.2.250
    ...

  app:
    ...
    networks:
      ab-net:
        ipv4_address: 10.1.2.11
    ...

networks:
  ab-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.1.2.0/23
          gateway: 10.1.2.1
```

The firewall (which is out of my control and can't be changed) allows direct incoming connections to 10.1.2.0/23 via containers' gateway 10.1.2.1 (which is the firewall itself) and not to the host.

Running the container with that configuration, docker configures a br-interface on the host with IP 10.1.2.1; thus on the network there are two machines with the same IP: the host and the firewall/gateway.

Containers have access to the internet, they see each others and from the host machine I can connect to the containers.

How can I have that scenario working? At this stage I would prefer not to use any orchestration tool, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the only option to do that is using the (currently) experimental feature "[Ipvlan Network](https://github.com/daftano/docker/blob/master/experimental/vlan-networks.md)".

> The Linux implementations are extremely lightweight because rather
>   than using the traditional Linux bridge for isolation, they are simply
>   associated to a Linux Ethernet interface or sub-interface to enforce
>   separation between networks and connectivity to the physical network.

The [documentation](https://github.com/daftano/docker/blob/master/experimental/vlan-networks.md) is quite large and can't be copied here, however those are the commands I had to run to achieve that:

```
echo 8021q >> /etc/modules
modprobe 8021q
apt-get install vlan
edit /etc/network/interfaces

auto eth1.2320
iface eth1.2320 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device eth1

auto eth1.2321
iface eth1.2321 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device eth1

auto eth1.2322
iface eth1.2322 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device eth1

auto eth1.2323
iface eth1.2323 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device eth1

auto eth1.2324
iface eth1.2324 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device eth1

/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not set different network outsite docker's NAT.